# Working with Apache Sentry - Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, apache-sentry

I have configured Apache Sentry using Cloudera Manager in my machine, can anyone explain start up commands to work with Apache Sentry - Cloudera?

Comment: Are you done with strong authentication like kerberos.?

Comment: yeah .. can i know the login in command as well as few commands to start up with sentry

Comment: Can anyone help working with apache sentry ?

Answer (score 1):

for which services do you want to configure authorization via Sentry ?
..and which version of CM/CDH are you using ?

You can start creating policies either by using Hue's 'Security' menu, or by using commandline interfaces like e.g. `beeline` (to create policies for Hive/Impala), or `solrctl sentry` command for SOLR....depends on which service you want to handle. Recent versions of Sentry and CDH-Kafka can also manage Kafka ACLs.

Sentry uses the group-mapping mechanism from underlying Linux box, hence groups known in the OS can be used to grant permissions via Sentry.
Sentry follows RBAC (role based access control), means you first create role(s), then grant privileges to those role(s) and then link group(s) to your role(s).

Sample scenario: create an admin user in the CDH sandbox

```
beeline -n cloudera -u "jdbc:hive2://quickstart.cloudera:10000/default"
create role sentry_admin;
GRANT ALL ON SERVER server1 TO ROLE sentry_admin;
GRANT ROLE sentry_admin TO GROUP cloudera;

# add group cloudera to Sentry property "sentry.service.admin.group", so that user 'cloudera' can administrate privileges/roles/..
```

A more detailled explanation can be found here:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/sg_sentry_overview.html

HTH...

Comment: Is there anyway to add privilege to user directly?